# Weird behavior with MySQL GroupBy on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am writing a query that groups a table of users by `(height, sex)` and then gets the name of the user with the minimum weight for that combination of `height` and `sex`.

If you wanna skip to the actual query, here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2e9a51/2) with a minimal representative example.

If you don't want to open that url, here is what I am talking about. Given a table such as:

```
| height | sex    | name    | weight |
|-------:|--------|---------|--------|
| 100    | female | Alice   | 150    |
| 100    | female | Barbara | 130    |
| 100    | female | Candice | 100    |
```

and a query that does this as follows:

```
SELECT name, min(weight) from users
group by height, sex
```

Why does the query output:

```
|  name | min(weight) |
|------:|-------------|
| Alice | 100         |
```

What I actually want is `Candice, 100` not `Alice, 100`.

I figured out it chooses Alice because it is the first row, but why does it do that? It's really weird and unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a correlated subquery, but not with fancy logic:

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.weight = (select min(u2.weight)
                  from users u2
                  where u2.height = u.height and u2.sex = u.sex
                 );
```

That is, return the users whose weight is the minimum for the `height`/`sex` combination.

Comment: This is a lot easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `GROUP BY` correctly. It is a general rule in most RDBMS that all non-aggregated columns must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. Only ancient versions of MySQL allow breaking that rule (in newer versions, you need to disable option `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`), but that can lead to unpredictable results, as you are experiencing here.

To exhibit the user that has the smallest `weight` within groups of recrods sharing the same `height` and `sex`, one solution would be to use a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM users u1
    WHERE 
        u1.height = u.height 
        AND u1.sex = u.sex
        AND u1.weight < u.weight
)
```

Rationale: the `NOT EXITS` condition combined with the subquery eliminates  records for which another record exists with the same `height` and `sex` but with a smaller `weight`, leaving in the result set only the record that has the smallest `weight` for each `height/sex` tuple. We use `SELECT 1` because we do not need the subquery to return an actual result, we just want to know if it returns *something*.

Comment: Can you explain that query? I'm fairly new to sql and i'm particularly lost about the `WHERE ... u1.weight<u.weight` and the `SELECT 1` aspects of the subquery. I don't see where the grouping by happens in this query. Which is weird because it does work.

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees: I updated my answer with more explanation

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "a smallest weight"?

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees: a *smaler weight*, a weight whose value is smaller.

Comment: "*It is a general rule in SQL that all non-aggregated columns must appear in the GROUP BY clause*" : Not completely true. Functionally dependent columns need not be in `GROUP BY` clause. It is specified ANSI SQL Standard 2003 as well. Do read: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html?m=1

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya: thanks for sharing this interesting reading! I do agree and I understand the notion of *functionnaly dependent column*. Sadly most RDBMS do not follow that track (whereas it would be possible for the query planner to check for the existence of a unique key in a `GROUP BY` list of columns). I rephrased my answer to be more precise on that point.

Answer (score 0):

With these data

```
CREATE TABLE users
(`height` varchar(8), `sex` varchar(8), `name` varchar(9), `weight` varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO users
(`height`, `sex`, `name`, `weight`)
VALUES
('100', 'female', 'Alice', '150'),
('100', 'female', 'Barbara', '130'),
('100', 'female', 'Candice', '100'),
('190', 'male', 'John', '185'),
('190', 'male', 'Bert', '130'),
('190', 'male', 'John', '113')
;
```

And this sql statement

```
Select name, u.weight
from users u inner join 
(Select min(weight) weight ,sex,height
From users
Group by height, sex ) u1 
On u.sex= u1.sex and u.height = u1.height
and u.weight = u1.weight
GROUP By u.height,u.sex;
```

You get following Result

```
name        weight
Candice     100
John        113
```

The second select statement u1 get u alle the minimum weghts for all groups sex and height, the rest is a simple inner join, where only the correlating names are chosen